# Volley is throwing an exception with no message

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm working on an android app where you're supposed to register as a driver or a rider. I'm using the volley library to store users' information on a database, now when I register as a rider, everything works just fine. However, when I try to register as a driver, it throws an exception with no message, so I don't even know what the deal is. I wrote constructors in the class which extends a StringRequest. With a hashmap that takes values with the same key names in both cases: the driver and the rider. 
I'm using a switch that distinquishes between the two cases. When turned on, you're registering as a driver. Otherwise, you're registering as a rider.

Here's the PostRequest class where the request constructors are written:

```
//The rider register request
    public class PostRequest extends StringRequest {
        private static final String register_url="http://pickmeapp.netai.net/register.php";
        private static final String logIn_url="http://pickmeapp.netai.net/db_functions.php";
        private Map<String,String> params;

                public PostRequest(String Name,String username,String password, String age,String gcm_id,String userType,Response.Listener<String> listener)
                {
                    super(Method.POST,register_url,listener,null);
                    params= new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("regId",gcm_id);
                    params.put("registerName",Name);
                    params.put("registerPassword",password);
                    params.put("registerUserName",username);
                    params.put("registerAge",age);
                    params.put("registerUserType",userType);
                }

        public PostRequest(String username,String password,Response.Listener<String> listener)
        {
            super(Method.POST,logIn_url,listener,null);
            params=new HashMap<>();
            params.put("UserName",username);
            params.put("Password",password);
        }

//The driver register request constructor
        public PostRequest(String Name,String username,String password, String age,String gcm_id,String carNumber,String carModel,String userType,Response.Listener<String> listener)
        {
            super(Method.POST,register_url,listener,null);
            params= new HashMap<>();
            params.put("regId",gcm_id);
            params.put("registerName", Name);
            params.put("registerPassword",password);
            params.put("registerUserName",username);
            params.put("registerAge",age);
            params.put("registerCarNumber",carNumber);
            params.put("registerCarModel",carModel);
            params.put("registerUserType",userType);
        }
        public Map<String,String> getParams()
        {
            return params;
        }
    }
```

And here's the code where I send the data to the server:

```
    private void WebServerRegistrationTask()  {
            String name,username,age,password;
            PostRequest registerRequest;
            name=nameEditText.getText().toString();
            username=userNameEditText.getText().toString();
            age=ageEditText.getText().toString();
            password=passwordEditText.getText().toString();

               final Response.Listener<String> gcm_database_listener= new Response.Listener<String>()
                {

                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LogIn.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                };
            try {
                if(aSwitch.isChecked())
                {
                    carNumberString= carNumberEditText.getText().toString();
                    carModelString=carModelEditText.getText().toString();
                    userType="driver";
                    Log.i("Car Number",carNumberString);
                    Log.i("Car Model", carModelString);
                    registerRequest=new PostRequest(name,username,password,age,gcmRegId,carNumberString,carModelString,userType,gcm_database_listener);
                }
                else {
                    userType = "rider";
                    registerRequest = new PostRequest(name, username, password, age, gcmRegId, userType, gcm_database_listener);
                }
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                requestQueue.add(registerRequest);
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }
```

It should be mentioned that when I tried to locate the exception using the logcat, it gave a NullPointerException:

```
log.e("Error is",ex.getMessage());
```

Comment: Check your logcat for the exact errors.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari The logcat is showing the same exact messages in both cases, let me edit the question so I can show the logcat

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Always try to demonstrate any failure, expected input/output as well as Logs that may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first problem is that you are not setting an error listener on volley! in your super call in PostRequest

```
super(Method.POST,register_url,listener,null);
```

that null is supposed to be your error listener so you know why something went wrong. Try this for your PostRequest class

```
public class PostRequest extends StringRequest {
        private static final String register_url="http://pickmeapp.netai.net/register.php";
        private static final String logIn_url="http://pickmeapp.netai.net/db_functions.php";
        private Map<String,String> params;

                public PostRequest(String Name,String username,String password, String age,String gcm_id,String userType,Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
                {
                    super(Method.POST,register_url,listener,errorListener);
                    params= new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("regId",gcm_id);
                    params.put("registerName",Name);
                    params.put("registerPassword",password);
                    params.put("registerUserName",username);
                    params.put("registerAge",age);
                    params.put("registerUserType",userType);
                }

        public PostRequest(String username,String password,Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
        {
            super(Method.POST,logIn_url,listener,errorListener);
            params=new HashMap<>();
            params.put("UserName",username);
            params.put("Password",password);
        }

//The driver register request constructor
        public PostRequest(String Name,String username,String password, String age,String gcm_id,String carNumber,String carModel,String userType,Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
        {
            super(Method.POST,register_url,listener,errorListener);
            params= new HashMap<>();
            params.put("regId",gcm_id);
            params.put("registerName", Name);
            params.put("registerPassword",password);
            params.put("registerUserName",username);
            params.put("registerAge",age);
            params.put("registerCarNumber",carNumber);
            params.put("registerCarModel",carModel);
            params.put("registerUserType",userType);
        }
        public Map<String,String> getParams()
        {
            return params;
        }
    }
```

then when you create a request also create an error lsitener and pass it in:

```
final Response.Listener<String> gcm_database_listener= new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {

                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LogIn.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    };

Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {

                    String error = e.networkResponse.statusCode + ": " + new String(e.networkResponse.data);
                    Log.e("Volley Error: ", error);
            }
        };
                try {
                    if(aSwitch.isChecked())
                    {
                        carNumberString= carNumberEditText.getText().toString();
                        carModelString=carModelEditText.getText().toString();
                        userType="driver";
                        Log.i("Car Number",carNumberString);
                        Log.i("Car Model", carModelString);
                        registerRequest=new PostRequest(name,username,password,age,gcmRegId,carNumberString,carModelString,userType,gcm_database_listener,errorListener);
                    }
```